# Why can't inner and outer selects be on the same object?

Tags: apex, soql, force.com

I have oppoortunities related to opportunities via a lookup, and a wanted to find all the opportunities with children opportunities.  When I did it, I got the error - that inner and outer selects should not be the same object type.

Here is the offending query:

```
Select id, name, stagename, (Select Id, name, stagename From Opportunities__r where stagename = 'Pre-Renewal' and type = 'Renewal') 
from opportunity 
where id in (select Parent_Opportunity__c from Opportunity)
```

Comment: @crmprogdev IMO, I find these to be 2 different questions.  First one is asking how to fix his error.  This question he encountered while trying to fix the original error and seems to be asking the **why**.  The 2 answers should end up very different with the way the questions were worded.

Comment: IMO, he's still trying to solve the problem he has with querying Opps that only have child Opps as one single query, thus the reason I feel it's a duplicate. As its written, it's a circular or non-selective query.

Comment: @crmprogdev can you elaborate on how it's non-selective?

Comment: Because of how it's written, it appears to me to be circular in nature, so therefore is non-selective. If you ran the outer query by itself, it doesn't appear as though you'd return a fixed set of results from which to capture the results on which to run the inner query. The answer to your original question & @JennyB answer below would seem to support that conclusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a step back for a moment and try just this part of the query:

```
Select id, name, stagename, (Select Id, name, stagename From Opportunities__r where stagename = 'Pre-Renewal' and type = 'Renewal') FROM Opportunity
```

I just tested out your scenario with a custom lookup field from Opportunity to Opportunity and the query did not error at all. I do see a problem with your WHERE clause because you cannot have the inner and outer selects on the same object type. 
It is mentioned in the docs [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm):

> You cannot query on the same object in a subquery as in the main
>   query. You can write such self semi-join queries without using
>   semi-joins or anti-joins. For example, the following self semi-join
>   query is invalid:
>
> ```
> SELECT Id, Name
> FROM Account
> WHERE Id In (
>    SELECT ParentId
>    FROM Account
>    WHERE Name = 'myaccount'
> )
> ```
>
> However, it is very simple to rewrite the query in a valid form, for
>   example:
>
> ```
> SELECT Id, Name
> FROM Account
> WHERE Parent.Name = 'myaccount'
> ```

So you would select all the parent opportunity ids from the children records instead like:

```
SELECT Parent_Opportunity__c , Id, Name, StageName FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName = 'Pre-Renewal and Type = 'Renewal' instead.
```